# rviz virtual joystick plug-in

Tags: rviz, joystick

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I'm sure I've seen that rviz has a virtual joystick plug-in. Any idea where I might find it (Publishing twist messages)? Looked around rviz/these answers and google and it doesn't seem obvious. (Unless I'm imagining things of course! :) )

Many Thanks

Mark

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/137276/rviz-virtual-joystick-plug-in/) by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1834 on 2014-03-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Maybe what you saw was the Robot Steering plugin in rqt.

---

Originally posted by [Girts L](https://answers.ros.org/users/3081/girts-l/) with karma: 196 on 2014-03-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on 2014-03-10**:
That looks like it'll do nicely. Thanks :)